# Arrange divs based on variable heights

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

This html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <blockquote>...</blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <blockquote>...</blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <blockquote>...</blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <blockquote>...</blockquote>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
  </div>
</div>
```

produces this layout:

[image: My Page looks like this]

Is there a way to achieve the following layout:

[image]

**Are there any frameworks/libraries that I should look into?**

Comment: Can you support flexbox and viewport units? If so, you can work out something quick and dirty like this with flex-direction: column:
```.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}```

Comment: I tried using the wrapper but all my divs populated horizontally across the screen.

Comment: Did not find the exact solution but, this site really helped me in getting a solution very close to what I want: http://flexboxfroggy.com/

`.wrapper { display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: center; }`